# Discontiguous array slices in Python

Tags: python, arrays, slice

I would like to get an array slice that has two (or more) discontiguous parts.

Example:

```
>>> a=range(100)
>>> a[78:80; 85:97] # <= invalid syntax
[78, 79, 85, 86]
```

That syntax is not accepted. What's the best way to do it?

**UPDATE:** Above example was on `int`, but I'd primarily like this to work on strings.

Example:

```
>>> a="a b c d e f g".split()
>>> a[1:3; 4:6]
['b', 'c', 'e', 'f']
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about

```
>>> a = range(100)
>>> a[78:80] + a[85:97]
[78, 79, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96]
```

Update:  Not sure what you want as the output for your string example:

```
>>> import string
>>> a = list(string.lowercase[:7])
>>> a[1:3] + a[4:6]
['b', 'c', 'e', 'f']
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'd like the solution to work for string as well, e.g., to get a two-part slice on `a="a b c d e f g".split()`. Added update to original question to clarify.

Comment: @Frank: What do you want the output to be of your example for a string?

Comment: See updated question: `>>> a="a b c d e f g".split()
>>> a[1:3; 4:6]
['b', 'c', 'e', 'f']`

Comment: sberry solution still will work, just add the two lists

Answer (score 1):

An ***alternative*** to sberry's answer (although I personally think his is better): Maybe you can use `itemgetter`:

```
from operator import itemgetter

a="a b c d e f g".split()

>>> print itemgetter(*range(1,3)+range(4,6))(a)
['b', 'c', 'e', 'f']
```

### ***OR***

```
from operator import itemgetter

a="a b c d e f g".split()

items = itemgetter(*range(1,3)+range(4,6))

>>> print items(a)
['b', 'c', 'e', 'f']
```